# Android facebook login - stuck on loading

Tags: android, facebook

I followed this tutorial to provide facebook login : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.2

Everything in my code is the same and it worked fine on all testing devices I had.

Just received an issue with stuck login on device Samsung A5 - android 6.0.1.

The flow of the issue is:
1. successful facebook login
2. successful logout (LoginManager.getInstance().logOut(); is called)
3. returned to LoginActivity
4. the second attempt to do facebook login from LoginActivity is not successful, user is stuck on login screen as seen on the screenshot below.

[image]

I found many issues here with stuck facebook login. But most of them have no answer or they have answer that does not work for me.

What is causing this issue? Why is it working on all devices except this one?
Any ideas?

Callback registration:

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
facebookLoginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(EMAIL));
facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                //success
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                //cancel
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                //error
            }
        });
```

Activity result (but I am not getting there):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 64206) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } 
}
```

Logcat is not showing any errors.
This is the log I get after clicking facebook login button:

```
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{7fbde01 V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id: time:15401189
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 4184
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 15401224
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
V/FA: onActivityCreated
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=4184, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoginActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-xxx}]
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=LoginActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-xxx, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=FacebookActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-xxx}]
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a06ce06 V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{64fbcc7 I.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 15401264
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5b65b7 V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that seems to cause the error?

Comment: did you debug it? adb logcat, for example? it´s nearly impossible to help without some debug info.

Comment: See edit. @luschn